# Phpize, Cannot find config.m4, Centos6, SAPRFC Install

Tags: php.ini, php

I'm trying to install a PHP module, which requires `phpize` and I'm being met with a warning, even though it exists and is installed.

`Cannot find config.m4.Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module`

So, I've tried running `phpize` from both root, with `/usr/bin/phpize` and just `# phpize`, still met with the same warning.

My PHP modules are stored in `usr/lib64/php/modules/` so I've tried running `phpize` from there, still the same warning.

`php-devel` is installed:

```
Package php-devel-5.3.3-14.el6_3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

`which phpize` yields this - `/usr/bin/phpize`

`find -name 'config.m4'` yields this - `find: File system loop detected; ./var/named/chroot/var/named' is part of the same file system loop as ./var/named'.`

So, I'm assuming `config.m4` either isn't in the same directory `phpize` is running from, or that loop error I'm getting is causing it to be hidden/not found, etc.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, SF.

**Edit:** I'm trying to build saprfc.sourceforge.net

Comment: What extension are you trying to build?

Comment: http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to give you the exact commands to run and in what order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.m4` should be in the current working directory of the extension you are trying to build.

So when you've downloaded the source PECL package, you would do it something like this

```
cd /usr/src
wget -O mypackage.tgz http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/saprfc/saprfc/1.4.1/saprfc-1.4.1.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsaprfc.sourceforge.net%2Fhome.php&ts=1349204180&use_mirror=heanet
tar xvfz mypackage.tgz
cd saprfc*
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

If you try and run `phpize` in another directory that isn't the source directory of a PHP extension; then of course it will complain that `config.m4` is missing.

Comment: Spot on.  I guess what I don't get is that when I `cd /usr/lib64/php/modules/saprfc/`, aren't I in the correct source directory of a PHP extension at that point?

Comment: Only if you downloaded the source to that location, otherwise, no.

Comment: Hm, I thought I did.  I had it placed in /usr/lib64/php/modules/saprfc/ and tried `phpize` from in there, but was met with that error.  Not sure why, total noob here, but thank you for the directions!  They were perfect... except that the install failed because it's dependent on another package.  Fixed my problem though!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that config.m4 is in the directory that contains the PHP module you are building.  If not, then something is missing when you extracted it.

In regards to "file system loop detected" with your `find` command.  Try using `locate` instead.  For me it's a lot easier when doing simple file searches.  Just make sure you do a `updatedb` first to update it's database.